# Hiera and puppet: I can't pass true as argument

Tags: automation, puppet, hiera

i have write a puppet's module and I want to use it with hiera for simply managing.
My problem is i can't pass true argument to a puppet's template.

Here my template file:

```
<%= @master %> // for test, show always 'false'
<% if @master -%>
hiera_config=$confdir/hiera.yaml
certname=puppet
dns_alt_names=puppetServer,puppet,puppet.xxx.net
<% end -%>
```

Hiera.yaml:

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: /etc/puppet/hieradata
:hierarchy:
  - "%{environment}" # test, production, etc.
  - "common"
  - "os/%{operatingsystem}"
  - "nodes/%{::fqdn}" # spécifique par client
```

PuppetServer.local.xxx.net:

```
---
classes:
  - common_xxx

common_xxx::master: true
```

common_xxx/manifests/init.pp:

```
class common_xxx
(
        ### Variable de classe ###
        $module_files = "puppet:///modules/$module_name",
        $master = false,
){
```

I use true/false parameter with another module (zabbix by wdijkerman) and it's work fine. I don't know why it's not work here.
Have you seen some mistake I have made ?

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you placing the `PuppetServer.local.xxx.net`? Is `PuppetServer.local.xxx.net` have a `.yaml` file extension? Does `PuppetServer.local.xxx.net` match the output of `facter -p fqdn`? Can you supply the error you are receiving?

Comment: Oh thanks it's working !
The fqdn was not the same.
Have a nice day.

Comment: You should put your resolution as an answer and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply rename my file PuppetServer.local.xxx.net to PuppetServer.local.xxx.fr with ptierno help.
Thank you again. ;)